# Redis replication and LFU caching

Tags: caching, redis, replication

I'm using Redis 4 with 3 instances, one master and two replicas. 
Master instance is configured to have maxmemory limit using the allkeys-lfu policy. 
I wonder should I forward my read queries also to master instance to make LFU policy work correctly. or I can forward them only to replicas and it still will work. ?

Answer (score 0):

> Slaves don't expire keys, instead they wait for masters to expire the
>   keys. When a master expires a key (or evict it because of LRU), it
>   synthesizes a DEL command which is transmitted to all the slaves.

according to: https://redis.io/topics/replication